# Activity invocation of onDestroy through finish method

Tags: java, android

Reading this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html#Destroy) for android development and noticed this little note at the end of the page:

> **Note:** The system calls onDestroy() after it has already called
>   onPause() and onStop() in all situations except one: when you call
>   finish() from within the onCreate() method. In some cases, such as
>   when your activity operates as a temporary decision maker to launch
>   another activity, you might call finish() from within onCreate() to
>   destroy the activity. In this case, the system immediately calls
>   onDestroy() without calling any of the other lifecycle methods.

- According to this note, there is a possibility for the `finish()` to
  be invoked even without `onPause()` or `onStop()`, does it mean that
  it should be recommanded to have a onDestroy() method calling
  explicitely the `onPause()` and `onStop()` methods?
- Or should the  code be duplicated there? (looks like a bad practice to me)
- Is there anyway to know if the methods have been invoked or not,
  meaning if it's a 'proper' finish or not?

Comment: what do you mean this "Or should the code be duplicated there"? You can override `onDestroy` and log some message to check if it is called.

Comment: What I meant is: should the code in onPause() and onStop() be called as well in onDestroy() in the case it is invoked from finish(), as it is mentioned that these methods invocation is skipped in such a case.

Comment: no. And what code are you planning to put in `onPause` and `onStop` and why would you call `finish` in `onCreate`?

Comment: It's just a something I was wondering reading the article, I do not have a specific scenario as of now but I can imagine one: let's say I initialize an handle on a sensor or camera, then a connection to an external resource (webserver for instance) and finally decide based on the sensor or camera definition that the user cannot use this activity (for any reason) and call the finish() method, I still have to release the camera and/or sensor right? As onPause() will not be invoked, it should then be done in onDestroy, isn't it?

Comment: no `onPause` will be invoked unless you call `finish` in `onCreate`. So release your camera in `onPause`.Check the doc http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html. Check the topic Releasing Camera.

Comment: That's the scenario of my question..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32722/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-clement)